# iOS - best architecture for localizing a storyboard Scene/ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have inherited an existing storyboard which has a viewController called loginScreen. It looks like something similar to this:

[image]

and this exists in the main.storyboard

We have created another target for a new product we are launching. This product is extremely similiar to the inital one i inherited so the target is a copy of the original.  To get to the point of the question on the login screen i showed a image of the UX team would like certain things changed here is an puesdo example of the things they want done:

[image]

Remember the two products share almost the entire same code.  so in one viewController UI the login screen is slightly different.  How can i achieve this cleanly ?  I could do something like this in the viewController.m:

```
//puedoCode
if(mySecondTarget){
moveButtonDown();
changeSpacingBetweenEntities();
//etc
}
```

but this spead all over my code is awful as it ties the UI logic to the code.
What i really wish i could do is make the viewControllers inside the storyboard localized per my product.  then i could have a single login screens for each target.  But my team does not want to localize a storyboard file. We want to keep the same storyboard file as its shared with another team we forked off and we want there updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Localizing" is a term that means translating to other languages.

I agree that you're best off having a custom storyboard per product - share the ViewController code and give each a custom look. If it were just colors & fonts I'd say look at NUI, but since you also have layout changes your code is going to get messy adjusting everything per product. At that point you may as well abandon storyboards and create the other product's UI all in code (not ideal IMHO, I'd rather use storyboards!)